# How to toggle a class through a Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, dropdown, toggle, addition

I'm trying to toggle a class on a *li* tag. It adds and removes the class from one element to another but not when I try to re-click a *li* with the class (active). What am I missing? Tried changing .classList.add to .classList.toggle but that didn't work.

```
(function(){
    
    let dropDowns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.template-nav > li'));
    
        const handleClick = (e) => {
            dropDowns.forEach(node => {
                node.classList.remove('active');
            });
            e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
    
        }
    
        dropDowns.forEach(node => {
            node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
        });
})();
```

See my work here:
https://jsfiddle.net/m5y46qv2/2/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you always remove the class from all nodes and then add the class to the click target. So, when you click the li with the class, you remove the class and then add it again. To prevent that, you need to not add the class again, if the node already had the class, when clicking.

For example:

```
(function(){

let dropDowns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.template-nav > li'));

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        let clickedNodeIsActive = e.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')
        dropDowns.forEach(node => {
            node.classList.remove('active');
        });
        if (!clickedNodeIsActive) {
            e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
        }

    }

    dropDowns.forEach(node => {
        node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    });
})();
```

Comment: This one worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine, you are just missing a small check to see if the clicked item already has the active class which means that you've clicked the same element. Something like this:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.target.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    dropDowns.forEach(node => {
      node.classList.remove('active');
    });

    e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah - that might be the solution. Missed the 'contains' code.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing some of the other solutions here but I still think this is worth posting, I'll explain the particular reasons, here's the code :

```
(function(){

let dropDowns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.template-nav > li'));

    const handleClick = (e) => {
      if (!e.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')) {
        dropDowns.forEach(node => {
            node.classList.remove('active');
        });
        e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
      } 
    }

    dropDowns.forEach(node => {
        node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    });
})();
```

2 reasons to do it this way :

1. place *all of the code* to remove *and* to add the `active` class inside of the `.contains('active')` check - no reason to remove classes if there's nothing to do.
2. use `e.currentTarget.classList.contains` not `e.target.classList.contains` - as `currentTarget` will act on the node you bound the event handler to, while `e.target` may be a pointer to a child node.